# Which ahadith quoted in al-Mustadrak are present in one or both sahihs?

Tags: hadith, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

I am looking for some of the ahadiths quoted by Mustadrak al-Hakim and are found in both muslim and bukhari or in one of them.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. What is your question? Please state your question clearly. You may refer to [ask] and take a [tour] in our [help].

Answer (score 1):

Among these ahadith which are quoted in either one or both sahihsyou may find:

In **the book of Adab** (in al-Mustadrak and in sahih al-Bukhari):

> 1. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The most awful (meanest) name in Allah's sight." Sufyan said more than once, "The most awful (meanest) name in Allah's sight is (that of) a man calling himself king of kings." Sufyan said, "Somebody else (i.e. other than Abu Az-Zinad, a sub-narrator) says: What is meant by 'The king of kings' is 'Shahan Shah.,"
>    (sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/230) and in [al-Mustadrak](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=7627&bk_no=74&flag=1) -only in Arabic-)

a similar version of this hadith appears in both sahihs ([Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/38/25) and [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/230)).

And in **the book of Riqaaq** -To make the Heart Tender- (in both al-Mustadrak and sahhih al-Bukhari) you may find:

> 2. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "There are two blessings which many people lose: (They are) Health and free time for doing good."
>    (sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/1) and in [al-Mustadrak](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=7748&bk_no=74&flag=1) -only in Arabic-)

In **the book of Dua'** (in al-Mustadrak) and the book of Riqaaq (sahih Muslim) you may find:

> 3. " O Allah, I seek refuge in Thee from the withdrawal of Thine blessing and the change of Thine protection (from me) and from the sudden wrath of Thine, and from every displeasure of Thine."
>    (Sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/49/8) and in [al-Mustadrak](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1832&bk_no=74&flag=1) -only in Arabic-)

Note that here the narrator chain are not that identic as al-Hakim narrates via [ibn Wahb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Wahb) (student of imam Malik and al-Laith ibn Sa'ad) in a longer chain and a slight difference in the wording.

Sources:
the book of Imam [ad-Dhahabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Dhahabi) called talkiss al-Mustadrak التلخيص (Summary of al-Mustadrak) and a thesis on the sahih qualification of [al-Hakim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Hakim_Nishapuri) and ad-Dhahabi called تصحيح أحاديث المستدرك بين الحاكم النيسابوري والحافظ الذهبي

See also [Is al Hakims Hadith collection Al Mustadrak reliable?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35749/is-al-hakims-hadith-collection-al-mustadrak-reliable)