# are there hadiths that are accounted as weak or fabricated just because of their texts while having good chains of transmission?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith

are there hadiths that are accounted as weak or fabricated just because of their texts while having good chains of transmission?

if yes, can you give examples?

as i see from these texts, hadith transmitters themselves can be accounted as weak or strong because of the hadithes they transmitted:

https://asar-forum.com/viewtopic.php?t=133 :

> А имам аз-Захаби в "аль-Мизан" отозвался о нем с похвалой, сказав, что
> хадисы его хорошие.
>
> Что же касается тех имамов, что считали Шаддада слабым, то они
> говорили так: «Нет проблем на него опираться», «не очень сильный» и
> т.д. Это не является словами, которые делают этого передатчика
> неприемлимым. Ибрахим ибн Абдуллах ибн Джунайд рассказывал: “Я спросил
> однажды Яхъю ибн Ма'ина о Шаддад ибн Са'иде, чьей куньей было Абу
> Тальха, и он сказал: “Надежный!” Я сказал ему: “Поистине, Ибн 'Ар'ара
> заявляет, что он слабый!” Тогда Яхья разозлился и стал что-то
> говорить, а все это слышал Абу Хайсама, который также сказал: “Шаддад
> надежный”. Имам Ибн 'Ади говорил: “Он не передавал много хадисов, но я
> не видел от него отвергаемых хадисов, и я считаю что нет в нем никаких
> проблем”. См. также “Икмаль тахзиб аль-камаль” 6/223.
>
> На основании сказанного следует, что хадисы такого передатчика не
> опускаются ниже уровня хасан (хороший). К тому же следует отметить,
> что из числа имамов, считавших его надежным - имам джарх уа та'диля
> Абу Хатим, о котором аз-Захаби говорил: “Если Абу Хатим называл
> кого-то надежным, то следуй его словам, ибо он не называл надежным
> никого, кроме того, чей хадис был достоверным!” См. “ас-Сияр” 13/260.

translation by google:

> And Imam al-Zahabi in al-Mizan praised him, saying that his hadiths
> are good.
>
> As for those imams who considered Shaddad weak, they said: “There is
> no problem to rely on him,” “not very strong,” and so on. These are
> not words that make this transmitter unacceptable. Ibrahim ibn
> Abdullah ibn Junaid said: “I once asked Yahya ibn Ma'in about Shaddad
> ibn Sa'id, whose kunya was Abu Talha, and he said:“ Reliable! ” I told
> him: "Verily, Ibn 'Ar'ara declares that he is weak!" Then Yahya got
> angry and began to say something, and all this was heard by Abu
> Haytham, who also said: "Shaddad is reliable." Imam Ibn 'Adi said: "He
> did not narrate many hadiths, but I did not see rejected hadiths from
> him, and I believe that there are no problems in him." See also Ikmal
> Tahzib al-Kamal 6/223.
>
> Based on the above, it follows that the hadiths of such a transmitter
> do not fall below the level of hasan (good). In addition, it should be
> noted that among the imams who considered him reliable - Imam Jarh wa
> ta'dil Abu Hatim, about whom al-Zahabi said: “If Abu Hatim called
> someone reliable, then follow his words, for he did not name no one is
> reliable, except whose hadith was authentic! ” See al-Siyar 13/260.

Comment: Honestly I don't get what you are talking about. Please explain what you mean to ask!

Comment: @Medi1Saif if a hadith has isnad that looks good but text of it very wrong. in that case one of transmitters can be suspected in lying. if it is the last transmitter from whom hadith investigator heard it directly, then he can think about him "how this man can transmit such wrong hadith? i start to think about him as an unreliable transmitter".

Comment: Is your inquiry covered in [What is an example of a hadith that is sahih in chain but not sahih in content?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47090/what-is-an-example-of-a-hadith-that-is-sahih-in-chain-but-not-sahih-in-content/47338#47338). If yes mark your post as a duplicate of it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_hadith : " For many critics, the contradictions of hadith with natural law and with other hadith demonstrated that the traditional scientists of hadith (muhaddithin) had failed to find all false hadith and there must be something wrong with their method. Explanations of why this was included the neglect of hadith content (matn) by muhaddithin in favor of the evaluation of chain/isnad of the hadith. " , etc.

Comment: This is a wrong claim made by people who don't have knowledge on the topic. As scholars of hadith themselves made some criticism in order to keep the analysis, verification and qualification on going.